# Button click then redirect to a div

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a one page website and was wondering how to redirect to a div when the contact form is filled and submitted. This is an aspx page with a aspx.cs backcode. so on button click it goes into this method to send the message in the contact form.

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

After much research I added this to the Page_load method

```
<div class="footer-section" id="contact">

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?id=#contact");
        }
    }
```

this shows in the URL as the page refreshes but it still doesnt redirect to the current div in the web page. When I press the enter key on the URL it does redirect manually. What am I doing wrong? any help is appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

use Like this:

```
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx#contact");
```

By using `?id=` you are defining a query-string parameter with name `id` and value as `#contact` you need to use `#contact` to set the focus to contact div.

Comment: I have just tried that and it did did not redirect back to the dive but did add it to the URl and clicking enter on there, it did take it to the div manually